# Make QHorizontalLayout expand inside QFrame

Tags: qt, layout, qt-designer, qt4.8

I have a widget hierarchy like this, with a frame (in order to set a background color behind the buttons and label) and a horizontal layout as its direct child.

[image: Widget hierarchy]

However, the horizontal layout (red frame in below screenshot of Qt Designer) does not take up the whole space inside the frame. How can I do that? Changing the property "layoutSizeConstraint" does not work. The label is already set to "Expanding" in horizontal direction, but still it keeps its size – I can resize the horizontal layout manually, but it should fill the width automatically.

[image: Layout not expanded]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `frame` frame doesn't have a layout (it's shown on its icon in the tree). It's because you have added new `QHBoxLayout` and dragged it into a frame. You should remove this layout, drag the label and buttons to the `frame`, then open `frame`'s context menu and choose "Layout" option and choose desired layout.

Comment: This led me to the solution. I kept the layout inside the frame because I want to lay out the three children of course. But I had to right-click the frame and choose "Lay out" and then for example "Lay Out Horizontally". This will add an *invisible* layout around the frame which can be seen when scrolling down in the *frame's* properties. This is really stupid of Qt Designer. Thanks!

Comment: Now in fact you have 2 layouts, one is invisible and another is explicitly shown in the tree. It's no harm, but it's not perfect. If you followed my advise, you'd have one invisible layout.

Comment: But then how would I place the label and buttons *inside* the frame if I only have an invisible layout as parent of the frame?