# Displayin Image in QT

Tags: qt, pyqt, qt-designer

I want to display an image in qt . I have a frame and frame has a label .I can show image in the label but there is a size problem as you see in the image . I want to make equal label size to the frame but i could not . How can i do that ?

[image: sample image]

Comment: Your question is almost the same you asked before http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34138948/centralize-a-frame-in-another-frame-in-qt-designer. If you understand how to center the widget in the frame then you can also understand how to make the label fit the frame!

Comment: Oh yeah actually you taught me very well . Thank u so so so much !!

Answer (score 0):

In QtDesigner, select the containing frame, widget or box to layout it's content.

Select the frame like in your image above. And choose "Lay Out In A Grid." you may also try "Lay Out Horizontally" or "Lay Out Vertically".

So, to in turn lay out the frame, select the frame containing widget and choose "Layout ...".

[image]